Pylance in vscode cannot find system functions for Python 2.7
I have Python 2.7 installed on my computer and have correctly configured the path in vscode, but Pylance still prompts that it cannot find the system functions.


Due to some necessary reasons, I cannot switch to Python 3.x.
If I switch to Python 3 in VSCode, the issue doesn't occur. I am confident that my Python 2.7 is installed correctly, and the path configuration in VSCode is also accurate. How can I resolve this issue?

Python 2.7 is no longer supported by PyLance, port your code to Python 3

you can try to use an old version of PyLance, but that might not run on your current VSC

develop in Python 3, implement a few mock functions, like for print and call it my_print, and define different implementations depending on the Python version, in production use Python 2.7

or use a different dev editor like Komodo, PyCharm, ...

If you install an older version of Pylance as shown here, your problem will be solved.

The python extension no longer supports python 2.7 as of version 2021.10.

What can I do if I'm still on Python 2.7?
For auto-completion, you can turn off auto-completions, or select Pylance as your language server as it may provide a good experience if the code is compatible enough with Python 3. We will continue to support selecting Python 2.7 as an interpreter in your workspace. For tools that keep support for Python 2.7 in their actively maintained version, we will continue to support using them with Python 2.7.


https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Limited-support-for-Python-2.7

